# Access OrderRepositoryInterface interface from cron job

Tags: magento2, php, event-observer

I need to call API after user place order.

My issue is when my event method called after placing order it initializes variables as shown in the constructor.

```
public function __construct(  
OrderRepositoryInterface $OrderRepositoryInterface , ScopeConfigInterface 
$scopeConfig
) {
    $this->orderRepository = $OrderRepositoryInterface;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->_resources = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
        ->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $this->_resources->getConnection();
    $table = $this->_resources->getTableName('order_fullfill');
}
```

But when I am calling a method from cron job suppose `init()`, how would I initilize `$this->orderRepository` and `$this->scopeConfig`.

```
function init()
{
    $this->orderRepository = $this->ObjectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepository');

    $this->scopeConfig = \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface\objectManager::getInstance();
    $this->_resources = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
        ->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $this->_resources->getConnection();
    $table = $this->_resources->getTableName('order_fullfill');
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to worry about because `ObjectManager` takes care of it for you in the background.

Besides using `ObjectManager` directly is considered a bad practice. Instead, initialise `OrderInterface` in the constructor of your cron class and then use it in your method.

Example:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface
 */
private $order;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order
 */
public function __construct(

    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order
) {

    $this->order = $order;
}

public function youMethod()
{
    $billingAddress = $this->order->getBillingAddress();

    return $billingAddress;
}
```